# Any other way to perform python operation

Tags: python

Requesting to edit the program.

```
for i in range(0, 2 ** 24):
byte3 = i & 0xff
byte2 = i & 0xff00
byte1 = i & 0xff0000
byte0 = i & 0xff000000
print('%d.%d.%d.%d' % (byte0 >> 24, byte1 >> 16, byte2 >> 8, byte3))
```

Comment: I fixed the indentation, make sure it is the same as in your code.

Comment: are you just trying to enumerate all the ips? ... i think you can do that without math ... which is probably a bit faster

Comment: @JoranBeasley how? Are there any modules that i could add and use i used ipaddress module but i keep getting errors.

Comment: @TheCharismaticSid `ipaddress` is the module to use. “I used ipaddress module but I keep getting errors” isn’t something anyone can debug for you, but if you show us your code and errors and explain what you’re trying to do, we can help you fix it.

Comment: @TheCharismaticSid I would consider updating your title and question to reference "ipaddress". Could help you get more useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really just trying to enumerate all possible IP addresses, this is a more pythonic way to do it than bit shifting:

```
from itertools import product
r = range(256)
addrs = map(lambda x: '.'.join(str(d) for d in x), product(r, repeat=4))
```

This has the benefit of being almost immediate, so that if you want to get them one at a time you don't have to wait for a massive list to be calculated. `itertools.product` will return a generator that iterates through the cartesian product of r with itself 4 times. This will create tuples like `(0, 0, 0, 0)`, so we use `map` to apply a lambda to each tuple that will convert the integers to strings and join them with a `.` character.

Then, if you want to print them, you can do the following:

```
while addrs:
    print(next(addrs))
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

1. It wasn't indented correctly (probably a copy and paste error).
2. There are 32 bits worth of information stored in an IP, so I changed it to `2 ** 32`.

Code:

```
for i in range(2 ** 32):
    byte3 = i & 0xff
    byte2 = i & 0xff00
    byte1 = i & 0xff0000
    byte0 = i & 0xff000000
    print('%d.%d.%d.%d' % (byte0 >> 24, byte1 >> 16, byte2 >> 8, byte3))
```